# Sudoku solver in Javascript using backtracking and recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, backtracking

I try to write a sudoku solver in Javascript but can't seem to make it work.

Every time my solve function returns undefined, it seems that when the code meets a dead end, it does not try another z in the previous function called and just gives up at some point after multiple tries on the same case

```js
var solve = () => {
//iterate through the lines of the grid 
    for (y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
        //iterate through each column of the grid
        for (x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
            //if a case is empty, we can try some numbers
            if (grid[y][x] === "") {
                //our answer must be between 1 to 9 to be correct
                for (z = 1; z < 10; z++) {
                    if (possible(x, y, z)) {
                        grid[y][x] = z.toString();
                        solve();
                        if (isComplete()) {
                            return grid;
                        }            
                        else {
                            grid[y][x] = "";
                        }
                    }
                }
                //if there is no answer, we go back to our precedent function call and try another number 
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

//get all the values of the vertical line of a particular value 
var getVerticalLine = (x, y) => {
    let verticalLine = [];
    //iterate through every line of the grid and add the value at the index except the one from the line where the value is taken from 
    for (let line of grid) {
        if (line != grid[y]) {
            verticalLine.push(line[x]);
        } 
    }
    return verticalLine;
}

var getSquareValues = (x, y) => {
    let squareValue = [];

    //check in which square our value is and create an array with each value from the square except our own
    if (x < 3 && y < 3) {
        //iterate through line 1 to 3
        for (let line = 0; line < 3; line++) {
            //iterate through columns 1 to 3
            for (let column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
                //check that we don't include our own value
                if (!(line === y && column === x)) {
                    squareValue.push(grid[line][column]);
                }
            }
        }
        return squareValue;  
    } else if (x < 6 && y < 3) {
        //iterate through line 1 to 3
        for (let line = 0; line < 3; line++) {
            //iterate through columns 4 to 6
            for (let column = 3; column < 6; column++) {
                //check that we don't include our own value
                if (!(line === y && column === x)) {
                    squareValue.push(grid[line][column]);
                }
            }
        } 
        return squareValue;
    } else if (x < 9 && y < 3) {
        //iterate through line 1 to 3
        for (let line = 0; line < 3; line++) {
            //iterate through columns 6 to 9
            for (let column = 6; column < 9; column++) {
                //check that we don't include our own value
                if (!(line === y && column === x)) {
                    squareValue.push(grid[line][column]);
                }
            }
        }
        return squareValue;
    } else if (x < 3 && y < 6) {
        //iterate through line 4 to 6
        for (let line = 4; line < 7; line++) {
            //iterate through columns 1 to 3
            for (let column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
                //check that we don't include our own value
                if (!(line === y && column === x)) {
                    squareValue.push(grid[line][column]);
                }
            }
        }
        return squareValue;
    } else if (x < 6 && y < 6) {
        //iterate through line 4 to 6
        for (let line = 3; line < 6; line++) {
            //iterate through columns 4 to 6
            for (let column = 4; column < 6; column++) {
                //check that we don't include our own value
                if (!(line === y && column === x)) {
                    squareValue.push(grid[line][column]);
                }
            }
        }
        return squareValue;
    } else if (x < 9 && y < 6) {
        //iterate through line 4 to 6
        for (let line = 3; line < 6; line++) {
            //iterate through columns 6 to 9
            for (let column = 6; column < 9; column++) {
                //check that we don't include our own value
                if (!(line === y && column === x)) {
                    squareValue.push(grid[line][column]);
                }
            }
        }
        return squareValue;
    } else if (x < 3 && y < 9) {
        //iterate through line 6 to 9
        for (let line = 6; line < 9; line++) {
            //iterate through columns 1 to 3
            for (let column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
                //check that we don't include our own value
                if (!(line === y && column === x)) {
                    squareValue.push(grid[line][column]);
                }
            }
        }
        return squareValue;
    } else if (x < 6 && y < 9) {
        //iterate through line 6 to 9
        for (let line = 6; line < 9; line++) {
            //iterate through columns 1 to 3
            for (let column = 3; column < 6; column++) {
                //check that we don't include our own value
                if (!(line === y && column === x)) {
                    squareValue.push(grid[line][column]);
                }
            }
        }
        return squareValue;
    } else if (x < 9 && y < 9) {
        //iterate through line 6 to 9
        for (let line = 6; line < 9; line++) {
            //iterate through columns 1 to 3
            for (let column = 6; column < 9; column++) {
                //check that we don't include our own value
                if (!(line === y && column === x)) {
                    squareValue.push(grid[line][column]);
                }
            }
        }
        return squareValue;
    } else {
        return "Some fuckery went there";
    }
}

var possible = (x, y, z) => {

    x = x.toString();
    y = y.toString();
    z = z.toString();

    if (!(grid[y].includes(z)) && !(getVerticalLine(x, y).includes(z)) && !(getSquareValues(x, y).includes(z))) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

var isComplete = () => {
    for (let y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
        //iterate through each column of the grid
        for (let x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
            if (grid[y][x] === "") {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

var setExemple1 = () => {
    grid = [["3", "", "6", "5", "", "8", "4", "", ""], 
         ["5", "2", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""], 
         ["", "8", "7", "", "", "", "", "3", "1"], 
         ["", "", "3", "", "1", "", "", "8", ""], 
         ["9","", "", "8", "6", "3", "", "", "5"], 
         ["", "", "", "", "9", "", "6", "", ""], 
         ["1", "3", "", "", "", "", "2", "5", ""], 
         ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "7", 4], 
         ["", "", "5", "2", "", "6", "3", "", ""]];
}
```

Thank you for your help !

EDIT : One of the problems was just that I forgot to declare my variables in my for loops ... I can't say how much time I spend looking at my code trying to understand where I did made a mistake when it was just this, thank you really much it seems to work better. I'm now able to complete the empty grid, there seems to be another problem trying to solve my example, I'll take a look into it

LAST EDIT : Finally made my code work ! There was a problem with my getSquareValues, at some point I made a mistake in the values used, there was a 4 and a 7 that I forgot instead of a 3 and a 6 and it made the function goes wrong :

```js
//get all the values of the vertical line of a particular value 
let getVerticalLine = (x, y) => {
    let verticalLine = [];
    //iterate through every line of the grid and add the value at the index except the one from the line where the value is taken from 
    for (let line of grid) {
        if (line != grid[y]) {
            verticalLine.push(line[x]);
        } 
    }
    return verticalLine;
}

let getSquareValues = (x, y) => {
    let squareValue = [];
    let bx = Math.floor(x / 3);
    let by = Math.floor(y / 3);
    for (let line = by * 3; line < by * 3 + 3; line++) { 
        for (let column = bx * 3; column < bx * 3 + 3; column++) {
            if (!(line === y && column === x)) {
                squareValue.push(grid[line][column]);
            }
        }
    }
    return squareValue;
}

let possible = (x, y, z) => {

    x = x.toString();
    y = y.toString();
    z = z.toString();

    if (!(grid[y].includes(z)) && !(getVerticalLine(x, y).includes(z)) && !(getSquareValues(x, y).includes(z))) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

let isComplete = () => {
    for (let y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
        //iterate through each column of the grid
        for (let x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
            if (grid[y][x] === "") {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

let solve = () => {
    //iterate through the lines of the grid 
        for (let y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
            //iterate through each column of the grid
            for (let x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
                //if a case is empty, we can try some numbers
                if (grid[y][x] === "") {
                    //our answer must be between 1 to 9 to be correct
                    for (let z = 1; z < 10; z++) {
                        if (possible(x, y, z)) {
                            grid[y][x] = z.toString();
                            solve();
                            if (isComplete()) {
                                return grid;
                            }            
                            else {
                                grid[y][x] = "";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //if there is no answer, we go back to our precedent function call and try another number 
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

let setExemple1 = () => {
    grid = [
        ["3", "", "6", "5", "", "8", "4", "", ""], 
        ["5", "2", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""], 
        ["", "8", "7", "", "", "", "", "3", "1"], 
        ["", "", "3", "", "1", "", "", "8", ""], 
        ["9","", "", "8", "6", "3", "", "", "5"], 
        ["", "5", "", "", "9", "", "6", "", ""], 
        ["1", "3", "", "", "", "", "2", "5", ""], 
        ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "7", "4"], 
        ["", "", "5", "2", "", "6", "3", "", ""]
    ];
}

let setExemple2 = () => {
    grid = [
        ["", "", "", "2", "6", "", "7", "", "1"], 
        ["6", "8", "", "", "7", "", "", "9", ""],
        ["1", "9", "", "", "", "4", "5", "", ""],
        ["8", "2", "", "1", "", "", "", "4", ""],
        ["", "", "4", "6", "", "2", "9", "", ""],
        ["", "5", "", "", "", "3", "", "2", "8"],
        ["", "", "9", "3", "", "", "", "7", "4"],
        ["", "4", "", "", "5", "", "", "3", "6"],
        ["7", "", "3", "", "1", "8", "", "", ""]
    ];
}
```

Comment: Hey there and welcome to SO. Can you make a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet) by clicking the `<>` icon in the editor. This way we can experience and debug your script.

Comment: First thing to look at: you're not declaring your variables.  A loop like `for (line = 3; line < 6; line++) {...}` should really read `for (let line = 3; line < 6; line++) {...}`.  And similarly, lines like `verticalLine = [];` should read `let verticalLine = [];`.  This may not fix your issue, but it would be a useful start.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thank you, it was effectively part of the problem, now I'm able to solve an empty grid. I tried solving few examples but it keeps returning undefined, I'll take a look into it

Comment: I haven't looked closely at the code, and my next suggestion definitely won't fix your problem, but it should clean up the code *a lot*:  in `getSquareValues` you could replace your nine repetitive `if-else` clauses by calculating box number: `let bx = Math.floor(x / 3); let by = Math.floor(y / 3)`.  Then `for (let line = bx * 3; line < bx * 3 + 3; line++) {  for (let column = by * 3; column < by * 3 + 3; column++) { ...`

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thanks, it's way simpler than my code, it took me time to understand it

Comment: @ScottSauyet after using let getSquareValues = (x, y) => {
    let squareValue = [];
    let bx = Math.floor(x / 3);
    let by = Math.floor(y / 3);
    for (let line = by * 3; line < by * 3 + 3; line++) { 
        for (let column = bx * 3; column < bx * 3 + 3; column++) {
            if (!(line === y && column === x)) {
                squareValue.push(grid[line][column]);
            }
        }
    }
    return squareValue;
}
It perfectly worked ! It solved my two examples !

Comment: @Elkmar: Congratulations! A suggestion: when things seem too complex, they usually are.  Look for simplifications.

Comment: @Elkmar: One other point.  The conventions of StackOverflow make editing a question perfectly acceptable.  But it should be done to add clarifications and additional details, not to change the code in the question, unless that clarifies the question.  However, it's also fine to answer your own question.  So next time, if you end up with a fixed version you want to describe, add an answer instead.  Best of luck!